# How to unselect selected cell in WPF DataGrid with SelectionUnit = Cell

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I'm working with VS2015 on a WPF application.
On one of my WPF windows, I got a DataGrid with SelectionUnit = Cell and SelectionMode = Single.
Furter I got a method to move rows inside the DataGrid up and down for sorting.
The sorting works but the problem is that the last cell which was selected by the mouse cursor is visually always selected (blue background), which could disturb the user.
So i tried to remove that visual marking of the cell by the following code lines:

```
datagrid.UnselectAllCells();
datagrid.SelectedCells.Clear();
```

None of the two lines works for me.
The last selected cell is still selected.

How can I remove that selection?

Any help would be appreciated.

At last a snippet from the XAML with the definition of the DataGrid:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="grdGraphicalElementMatrix" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"
          HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
          CanUserAddRows="True" 
          IsReadOnly="False"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          SelectionUnit="Cell" SelectionMode="Single"
          CurrentCellChanged="grdGraphicalElementMatrix_CurrentCellChanged"
          ItemsSource="{Binding GraphElemMatrix}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="colXAssignment"
                            Width="1*"
                            Binding="{Binding Path=X}"
                            Header="X"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="colYAssignment"
                            Width="1*"
                            Binding="{Binding Path=Y}"
                            Header="Y"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

grdGraphicalElementMatrix_CurrentCellChanged is a method in which i can get the selected row and column when the user clicked in one of the cells to select it.

```
    private void grdGraphicalElementMatrix_CurrentCellChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (grdGraphicalElementMatrix.CurrentCell != null && grdGraphicalElementMatrix.CurrentCell.Column != null)
        {
            vm.GrdGraphicalElementMatrixSelColIndex = grdGraphicalElementMatrix.CurrentCell.Column.DisplayIndex;
            vm.GrdGraphicalElementMatrixSelRowIndex = grdGraphicalElementMatrix.Items.IndexOf(grdGraphicalElementMatrix.CurrentItem);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you using the MVVM pattern to bind to your DataGrid? If so I can suggest to bind the SelectedItem property to a property in your model - which you can set to null and it should unselect the item in the grid.

Comment: @Johan: Hello Johan. Yes i'm using MVVM but i cannot use SelectedItem because of SelectionUnit Cell. SelectedItem would only work with SelectionUnit Row. Isn't it or am i wrong?

Comment: Oh I see, the Row selection is not the problem, but rather the individual cell? Which DataGrid are you using?

Comment: @Johan: I'm using the standard DataGrid of Visual Studio 2015, .NET Framework 4.5.2.

Comment: Do you mind adding the xaml of your Datagrid to your question?

Comment: @Johan: I added a snippet from the XAML and a little bit of code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173948/discussion-between-johan-aspeling-and-patrick-pirzer).

Comment: I have set up a testing app which loads mock data, with similar properties to your DataGrid. I have a button at the bottom that should clear the selection, and I am passing the DataGrid through as a command parameter - and the `UnselectAllCells()` method is clearing the selection on my datagrid. You can try  binding to the `CurrentCell` to see what happens in the setter when it is changing? Maybe that event is re-selecting the cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have set up a testing app which is able to clear the DataGrid Selection - with the following:

**View**

```
<DockPanel>
    <Button Content="Clear Selected" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Command="{Binding ClearGridCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=datagrid}"/>
    <DataGrid x:Name="datagrid" 
            CurrentCell="{Binding SelectedCell, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
            SelectionMode="Single" 
            SelectionUnit="Cell" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
            Margin="10" 
            VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}" 
            CanUserAddRows="True" 
            IsReadOnly="False"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="No"></DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</DockPanel>
```

Note I am passing the Datagrid through to the Button Command via the CommandParameter

**DataContext**

```
private object selectedCell = null;

public object SelectedCell {
    get { return this.selectedCell; }
    set {
        if (this.selectedCell != value) {
            this.selectedCell = value;
            SetPropertyChanged("SelectedCell");
        }
    }
}

public void ClearGrid(object obj) {
    var dg = obj as DataGrid;
    if (dg != null) {
        dg.UnselectAllCells();
    }
}
```

Maybe you can get more information by debugging the setter in the `SelectedCell`. Maybe it is clearing, but re-selected through your `grdGraphicalElementMatrix_CurrentCellChanged` method?

Comment: Hello Johan. You are right. The CurrentCellChanged-event causes the calling of the setter. Do i have another possibility to detect the row and column indices of the selected cell at runtime?

Comment: Hello. I removed the CurrentCellChanged-event and transfered the code for getting the row and column to the getters of two properties by which i cant get them in other methods. The Setter of CurrentCell is now only called once when i start the window. But as i'm moving a row up or down, the last selected cell appears still selected.

Answer (score 1):

Thank You very much for Your help and useful hints.
Thanks to You i have found a solution which works.

First i have replaced the CurrentCellChanged-event by the SelectedCellsChanged-event.
Then i reprogrammed in the method for moving a selected row up or down.
Here the new code for unselecting the cell which is at the old row-index and selecting the cell at the new row-index.

```
// UnselectAllCells was correct.
datagrid.UnselectAllCells();
// But a refresh is needed. This was missing.
datagrid.Items.Refresh();
// Selects the cell in the moved row. Focus is needed, so the cell appears selected all the time.
datagrid.CurrentCell = new DataGridCellInfo(datagrid.Items[newIndex], datagrid.Columns[GrdGraphicalElementMatrixSelColIndex]);
datagrid.SelectedCells.Add(datagrid.CurrentCell);
datagrid.Focus();
```

Comment: Glad to have helped!